# Migrate exoplayer 2.8.4 to 2.9.0

Tags: java, android, exoplayer

I trying to update exoplayer 2.8.4 to 2.9.0.
But now I have this error in the compilation process :

```
ERROR: HlsSampleStreamWrapper.java:174-175: Lambda coming from jar file need their interfaces on the classpath to be compiled, unknown interfaces are java.lang.Runnable
```

Here my complete gradle file :
https://pastebin.com/e2DKAvmF

Any idea about the problem ?

Thx for your help.

Comment: Self answer : works after upgrate Gradle.